# VSIX WPF Wizard Instead of Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding, vsix

I'm working on an extension for Visual Studio and I'm currently looking at using WPF instead of Forms for the template wizard.

I've got it all working with Forms but I much prefer the look of and working with WPF, but I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible - or how I should go about doing it properly.

My VSIX consists of your typical layout, it's a solution with 3 projects;
1. **MyProjectTemplate** *(C# Project Template)*
2. **MyProjectVSX** *(C# VSIX Template)*
3. **MyWizardWPF** *(WPF App)*

I'm also using MahApps.Metro to make it look a bit sleeker. Added *(via NuGet)* and referenced by both MyProjectVSX and MyWizardWPF.

And while it works - the WPF shows up when I go to create a template - it is completely and utterly missing any styles. It basically just looks like a Windows 95 application.

I'm assuming this is related to the App.xml and it being unable to locate it. But I'm at a complete loss at how to tie all of this together. I get a bunch of warnings that it was unable to find various style related things. For example;

> System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground'
>   System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='MahApps.Brushes.ThemeForeground'

I've tried playing around with the ResourceDictionary URIs, copying the App.xml to my VSX project. Tried building it as a class library instead of an application but to no avail.

Is what I'm trying to achieve here feasible...?

Answer (score 1):

Well I was able to reference MahApps.Metro. Seems like I was vastly over-looking it all. I'm still not sure if this is the *right* way to do it, however. But it works.

I referenced MahApps.Metro inside the Window.xaml itself instead of via the App.xaml, like so;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--  MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive!  -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <!--  Accent and AppTheme setting  -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Dark.Blue.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

This also works if I create a WPF User Control which will make the overall project a bit less bloated - but the designer will not be using MahApps.Metro styles. I have yet to find a fix for this.